# ¿Declarar variable JavaScript dinámicamente?

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables

Reformulo mi pregunta original incluyendo código explícito para una mejor comprensión de la inquietud que tengo.

Tengo identificado al usuario "Jhon Doe" en una variable.

```
var usuario = "JhonDoe";
```

Mediante una consulta AJAX a una página PHP, busco en una base de datos MySql todos los ID en una tabla donde el usuario esté presente:

1° JS

```
// variable global
var respuesta;
var IDs = new Array();
//----------------------
$.ajax({
            url: "ejemplo.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {user: usuario},
            success:  function (response){
                
                respuesta = response;
            }
        });
```

2° PHP

```
// Ejecuta la consulta y almacena el resultado en "$respuesta". En este ejemplo la respuesta es "1-4-31" ya que se ha encontrado al ususario en los ID de la tabla números 1, 4 y 31.

echo $respuesta;
```

Transformo la respuesta en un array

```
// variable global
var respuesta;
var IDs = new Array();
//----------------------

var IDs = respuesta.split('-');
```

Ahora que poseo en un array todos los ID donde Jhon está presente, deseo crear un objeto por cada ID del array.
Es aquí donde no sé cómo proseguir.

Lo que he intentado:

```
function presencia (datos){
this.datos = datos;
}

IDs[0] = new presencia("algun dato");
alert (IDs[0].datos);
```

No consigo representar "IDs[0]" como un nombre de variable para asignarle datos.

Espero se entienda mejor.
Saludos!!! :D

Comment: Hola @Pablo, básicamente, ¿quieres formar un `array` de objetos?

Comment: Puedes poner el resultado que esperas?

Comment: Podria ser un array de objetos.
El resultado que espero es poder invocar:
IDs[0].almacenarValor("Algun Valor");
IDs[1].almacenarValor("Algun Valor");
IDs[0].imprimirValor();
IDs[1].imprimirValor();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a suponer que lo que obtienes de tu backend es una serie de valores separados por guiones (no sé si son numéricos o no, pero creo que no influye en la solución.
Vamos a analizar lo que estás haciendo:

```
// variable global
var respuesta;
var IDs = new Array();
//----------------------
$.ajax({
        url: "ejemplo.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {user: usuario},
        success:  function (response){
            
            respuesta = response;
        }
    });
```

Voy a suponer que el resto de la lógica la estás aplicando dentro de la función success o desde ahí llamas a otra función donde procesas la respuesta, porque si no, no podrías acceder a los datos. Por tanto, realmente las variables globales son innecesarias, podrías escribir el código así:

```
//creamos una clase Presencia
class Presencia {
  constructor(d) {
    this.dato = d;
  }
  toString() { //método ejemplo para la clase
    return this.dato;
  }
}


$.ajax({
   url: "ejemplo.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {user: usuario},
   success:  function (respuesta){
     const listaId = respuesta.split('-');
     const listaPresencia = []; // array vacío
     
     listaId.forEach(id => {
       listaPresencia.push(new Presencia(id));
       console.log("creando objeto para "+ id);
     });

     //... hacer cosas con la lista

   }
});
```

Algunos apuntes: te recomiendo usar `let` y `const` en lugar de `var`. En general te aconsejo que revises las novedades de Javascript (ES2015 y posteriores) porque la sintaxis que usas está un poco anticuada. Esto es habitual si estás siguiendo alguna guía o documentación que tenga algunos años.

**PS**: el generar el array de Presencias se podría escribir de un modo más sencillo así:

```
const listaId = respuesta.split('-');
const listaPresencia = listaId.map(id => new Presencia(id))
//... hacer cosas con la lista de Presencias
```

Pero no lo puse originalmente porque quizá es más complicado ver el funcionamiento si no conoces el método map y las funciones flecha/lambda.

Comment: Así es, el backend devuelve los valores separados por guiones.
De la misma manera que con los datos que obtengo en success, son separados con split y luego utilizados.
Probaré el código y luego comento.
Muchas gracias por tu aporte!.
PD: En efecto estoy siguiendo guías y documentación no muy actual.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que lo que deseas hacer es crear una variable:

```
public id: number = 0;
```

No seria optimo crear una variable por cada elemento que esta dentro del arreglo si deseas manipular los datos que están dentro del arreglo te recomiendo que veas la funciones de `filter`, `some`, `forEach`, `map`.

Pero de todas maneras el codigo que muestras estaria incorrecto, el correcto seria:

```
public IDs: any[] = [];

function presencia (datos) {
    return this.datos = datos;
}

IDs.push(presencia("algun dato"));
alert (IDs);
```